# Regular Expression That Will Allow URL Redirect Of All URLs Without A String To Redirect To URL With That String

Tags: regex, iis, redirect

I have some versioned folders of site files that we are handling through IIS. What I need to do is create a URL Rewrite that will redirect traffic from all requests that don't match the most recent version, TO that most recent version. I'm having a difficult time as RegEx are not my specialty and I have been working on it for the last week.

Here's an example of what I need.

Most recent version:
https://testurl.com/v4/#

Older Versions:

https://testurl.com/#

https://testurl.com/v2/#

https://testurl.com/v3/#

These urls have other routes off of the base as well (ex. https://testurl/v3/#/rout1)

I'm needing a regular expression that will say "Any requested url that is does not contain the /v4/ to REDIRECT to the https://testurl/v4/#

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Side question, what's the point of having different versions if you're going to redirect them all to the latest version anyway? You may as well just not version your API at all

Comment: Because there are caching issues that we are currently working to resolve in the Angular Applications (this is a common issue from all of my research) that has us in a space where we are having to version that front-end files that call the API to ensure that the end user is getting the updated backend application.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will capture all domains of the form that you've listed. Capture group 1 will contain the actual route, eg `/` or `/rout1`.

```
/^https\:\/\/testurl\.com(?:\/v\d)?\/#(.*)$/
```

You can see it illustrated here: http://regexr.com/3fgo8